# Ada: What is the purpose of `limited` in `limited interface`

Tags: ada

I have started learning Ada a few weeks ago. I understand that `limited` in some contexts declares a limited type, for whom copying of objects is not allowed

From [Ada Reference Manual 2012 7.5 1/2](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-7-5.html)

> A limited type is (a view of) a type for which copying (such as for an assignment_statement) is not allowed. A nonlimited type is a (view of a) type for which copying is allowed.

However, since an `interface` type is inherently abstract, an 'interface object' cannot be created, and thus cannot be copied. Is keyword `limited` redundant here? What's the difference between `limited interface` and `interface`?

```
type Abstract_Fruit_Type is interface;
type Abstract_Fruit_Type is limited interface;
```

Comment: `limited` is not just for task and protected types. Any concrete type derived from a limited interface will be limited. But: "IMHO, Interfaces are worthless."--Randy Brukardt, ARG member and ARM editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key distinction is in [ARM 3.9.4 12/2](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-9-4.html)

> A type derived from a nonlimited interface shall be nonlimited.

So if you want to implement the interface with a limited type then you must mark the interface with **limited** keyword. Then you will be able to implement this interface with limited or non-limited types.

If you omit **limited** keyword in interface description then all its implementations will be non-limited types only.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out:
A `limited interface` can be used to extend a `synchronized interface` and its subcategories `task interface` and `protected interface`, while a (non-limited) `interface` cannot.

```
-- This is allowed

type Abstract_Type is limited interface;
type Task_Type is task interface and Abstract_Type;
```

```
-- This is not allowed
type Abstract_Type is interface;
type Task_Type is task interface and Abstract_Type;
-- error: (Ada 2005) task interface cannot inherit from non-limited interface
```

Both `task interface` and `protected interface`, and thus their parent -- all `synchronized interface` are inherently limited. [Ada Reference Manual 2012 3.9.4 12/2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-9-4.html) specifies the following

> A type derived from a nonlimited interface shall be nonlimited.

Which means

```
A type that is limited cannot be derived from a nonlimited interface.
```

Event though interface types themselves are abstract, they are used to create concrete types, whose objects can be defined. Due to the above restriction, the `limited` keyword in `limited interface` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`Limited` in Ada type declarations means "*this thing does not have assignment.*"

In Ada's `generic` or in `interface` the keywords like *limited* or *private* are inverted: you are saying "the thing being represented here cannot be assumed to have property X". So you *can* instantiate a private-typed generic-parameter with an Integer, but inside the generic itself you can only count on the properties from the generic formal specification.